# Is there a way to change current focus item in a RowList programmatically?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have a `RowList` with 1 row. I'd like to change the focus item to be one other than the first item in the row. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RowList.jumpToRowItem = [0, columnIndex]`

See here https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/list-and-grid-nodes/rowlist.md